# Cache Loading in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, postconstruct

I have a cache class that is loading properties from a .properties file before the application startup, in a **simple java project**. It logs out everything.I need to convert this project to springboot application.

What annotations can i use to achieve the Cache Loading??

Currently I wrote the code like my spring boot app starts with the @postconstruct , since i am not using web.xml for loading servlets.

```
@RestController
public class ConfigServlet {

    @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
    //business logic
    }
}
```

And this servlet starts up first. So how can i load cache along this??

It is supposed to load the Cache even before this servlet class loads. How can i achieve this concept??

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have below properties in your application properties. You can load them as below. The properties will be loaded during the application startup.

```
application.properties
    test.a = 10
    test.b =20
    test1.a = 30
    test1.b = 40

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
Class CacheProperties {

Map<String,String> test;
Map<String,String> test1;

public String getTestB() {

return test.get("b");

}

public String getTestA() {

return test.get("a");

}

public String getTest1B() {

return test1.get("b");

}

public String getTest1A() {

return test1.get("a");

}

//setters


}
```